# nginx rewrite for an url with parameters

Tags: nginx, configuration, redirect, rewrite

I have an URL of this type:

```
http://www.example.com/?param1=val1&param2=&param3=val3&param4=val4&param5=val5
```

And I want to redirect it to this one:

```
http://www.example.com/newparam/val3/val4
```

So I have tried this rewrite rule with no success:

```
rewrite "/?param1=val1&param2=&param3=(.+)&param4=(.+)&param5=(.+)" http://www.example.com/newparam/$1/$2 redirect;
```

Is nginx not able to deal with query parameters?

**EDIT:** I don't want to rewrite all petitions. I only need to rewrite that URL, without affecting the others.

Answer (score 20):

Ok, thanks to the initial help of rzab, I have redefined his rule to this working solution:

```
location / {
    if ($args ~* "/?param1=val1&param2=&param3=[0-9]+&param4=.+&param5=[0-9]+") {
        rewrite ^ http://www.example.com/newparam/$arg_param3/$arg_param4? last;
    }
}
```

I just added a condition to avoid infinite recursion, and a ? at the end of the rule to get rid of the [initial params](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite). It works perfectly :)

Comment: Query string allows a different order of parameters. So your `if` will stop working when e.g. `param2` goes before `param1`.

Comment: Interesting. In my case it will not occur because it's a clickable url in an e-mail, but it's good to know. Thanks.

Comment: its not working with alphanumeric query string

Answer (score 6):

```
location = / {
  rewrite ^ http://www.example.com/newparam/$arg_param3/$arg_param4;
}
```

Comment: So, must I write $arg_ and then the parameter name?

Comment: Yes, that would be the easiest.

Comment: Ok, but I don't want to rewrite all petitions. I only need to rewrite that URL, without affecting the others.

Comment: I have made some tests. That rule will generate an infinite redirection. I will write a new answer with the code I got to work. Thanks :)

Comment: I should probably mention, that you have to declare "location /" besides "location = /" to avoid recursion. I guess you'll have it to proxy_pass somewhere as the main route. "location = /" matches exactly / requests. Anyway, matching $args seems ok, except it'll match _any_ request with the parameters ?param1=val1&....

Comment: A bit more explanation in the answer would be helpful.