# Nginx Redirect regex

Tags: nginx, redirect, regex, url

I have this url:

```
https://example.com/admin/catalog/product/view/id/45533/?___store=en_us&sendAttributionID=email_automation_5ffa6c5967af4527508858fb&ContactID=5f9d9eac1215fsdfsdfasdffsdfsdf04ff6c98af
```

I need to redirect it with nginx to:

```
https://example.com/catalog/product/view/id/45533/?___store=el_gr&sendAttributionID=email_automation_5ffa6c5967af4527508858fb&ContactID=5f9d9eac1215fsdfsdfasdffsdfsdf04ff6c98af
```

In fact I need from first link:
To remove

```
admin
```

and replace:

```
en_us
```

with:

```
el_gr
```

I have this regex for now:

```
rewrite ^/admin/(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 permanent;
```

which removes the **admin** word. But I can't figure out how to replace the

```
en_us
```

After UML help now I am in:

```
rewrite ^/admin/(.*?)en_us(.*?)$ https://example.com/$1el_gr$2 permanent;
```

which in Online Regex works but not in nginx

Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**

I first thought that just changing the regex would help, like this:

```
rewrite ^/admin/(.*?)___store=en_us(.*)$ https://example.com/$1___store=el_gr$2 permanent;
```

However, as the rewrite matching only works on the "filename" part (up to ?), it won't work. Some other technique is required.

Comment: Thank UML. Unfortunately this regex is returning the initial link. Is not affecting anything

Comment: Okay, I have investigated the situation more. This won't work, as only the first part of the string (up to ?) is evaluated by the rewrite module. Maybe this answer can help: https://serverfault.com/questions/160790/nginx-rewrite-for-an-url-with-parameters

Comment: UML check my question again please....I just edited