# How to handle parameters in nginx rewrite urls

Tags: nginx

I have an URL of this type:
`https://mydomain.ltd/info/blahblah?cate=blahblah123`
And I want to redirect it to this one:
`https://mydomain.ltd/info/blahblah/blahblah123`

Server info / nginx 1.25.1 / php 7.4.33

Help me please!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nginx reverse proxy + URL rewrite](https://serverfault.com/questions/379675/nginx-reverse-proxy-url-rewrite) there is also [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/160790/nginx-rewrite-for-an-url-with-parameters?rq=1)  or also [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/67316/in-nginx-how-can-i-rewrite-all-http-requests-to-https-while-maintaining-sub-dom?rq=1) and similar like [this on](https://serverfault.com/questions/586586/nginx-redirect-via-proxy-rewrite-and-preserve-url?rq=1) question which is similar to your offtopic question