# nginx redirect subdirectory

Tags: nginx, redirect

```
rewrite ^/faq/(.*)$ /faq/$1 redirect;
```

I would like to redirect domain.tld/faq/* to domain.tld/faq/

Unfortunately, this leads to an endless loop.

Background: There was the FAQ url and very many other URLs in the FAQ directory. These no longer exist, but only the FAQ main page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nginx rewrite for an url with parameters](https://serverfault.com/questions/160790/nginx-rewrite-for-an-url-with-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use the capture group `$1` and make sure there's something after the `faq` by adjusting regex to use `+`:

```
rewrite ^/faq/(.+)$ /faq/ redirect;
```